# Can I add my application to the application bar programatically?

Tags: google-tv

Currently the application bar on the main Google TV contains google applications such as Live TV, YouTube, Market, Chrome, etc. I am wondering if it is possible to put my application in this bar upon install of my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's specifically designed so that the user has to do that.